# Hard quotes versus soft quotes. Which to use and when?

Tags: coding-style, quotes

This question has been bothering me for a while. I see alot of people using soft quotes in their code. I, however, use hard quotes almost everywhere. I think hard quotes might be better in some cases (like in PHP putting variables in a string with accolades). But what is now the difference between hard and soft quotes? Which one is better in what case? Are there any difference with the quotes in different languages? Will it affect speed? Please provide a full and detailed answer, if possible with sources, since this might be a good help to beginning programmers too. Thanks!

Comment: am i correct in assuming that by soft quote you are referring to `'` and hard quote as `"` ? google leads me to believe that this is not common terminology.

Comment: @AlexLynch you are correct that soft quote is `'` and hard quote `"`.

Comment: @lord_t I myself use PHP alot, but this might be relevant to a whole lot of other languages.

Comment: In most languages double quotes are used to define a string, whereas single quotes are used to define characters (well, 1 character)

Comment: @Bgi I can think only of the C-family languages that follow that convention. This is hardly "most" languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This topic cannot be discussed in a language-agnostic way, as many languages assign different semantics to the two kinds of quotes.

In some languages the two quoting styles mean radically different things: in the C language family, strings are enclosed in double quotes while characters are enclosed in single quotes; in Postgres, strings are enclosed in single quotes, while double quotes escape *identifiers*. In those languages you don't have any choice and must use the correct kind of quotes.

In other languages, there are *no* semantic differences between the two: Python does not differentiate between the two styles. In this case, it is probably worth it to pick one style over the other and stick with it, but it does not matter which one you prefer; the reason to pick a convention instead of using the two styles randomly is that it will save you from mismatched quotes in the future. There might also be a (very slight) performance advantage to pick the quoting style that will avoid backslashes, as their processing would be (very slightly) more expensive than non-special characters in the string.

In yet another family of languages, strings in single quotes are *not* parsed for variable interpolation, while variable references are replaced in double-quoted strings. There are still *more* different flavors even among those languages: for example, `bash` does not perform *any* parsing in single-quoted strings, meaning that you can't even backslash-quote literal single quotes there (`'foo\'bar'` is an error; you need `'foo'\''bar'` in order to include a literal single quote).

In languages that perform no escaping of any kind on single-quoted strings, those would be the best-performing type of string literal. After the opening quote, the parser is looking *only* for a closing quote (which can be optimized fairly well) and is not concerned with the actual contents of the string.

In languages that *do* inspect the content of the string, performance will vary proportionally to the grammar complexity. The string will *at least* have to be scanned for occurences of any special characters, and if there are any, they will need to be processed (e.g. backslashes might only skip the next character, but the parser might also need to inspect several characters after it, if the grammar allows for sequences like `\0x##`).

If the language allows variable interpolation within the string, its performance depends on the specific implementation. Parsing variable references within a `"foo $var bar"` string might be a complex process, but on the other hand `'foo '.$var.' bar'` involves two string concatenations, and concatenation is also an expensive process — each concatenation needs to allocate a new string and copy the two operands into it; this might turn out to be *very* expensive with long strings. A specific language's implementation might be better optimized to parse and replace variables within an interpolated string, and another implementation might be better at optimizing concatenation of multiple strings together (e.g. by using structures like [ropes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28computer_science%29) internally). Still, it is very unlikely to have vastly different performance for the two composition styles.